# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).jsGrid is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsgrid

In my page I'm trying to create a jsgrid table I think nothings wrong because I imported things right way but it gives me this;

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).jsGrid is not a function error

Is there something wrong because I didn't see any mistake about initializing the table?

And heres my code:

```
<script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsgrid/1.5.3/jsgrid.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/vendors/js/vendor.bundle.base.js"></script>
<script src="assets/vendors/js/vendor.bundle.addons.js"></script>
<script>
    $("#brands_table").html("asd");
    $("#brands_table").jsGrid({
        width: "100%",
        height: "400px",

        filtering: true,
        inserting:true,
        editing:true,
        sorting:true,
        paging:true,
        autoload:true,
        pageSize:10,
        pageButtonCount:5,
        deleteConfirm:"Silmek istediğinize emin misiniz?",

        controller:{
            loadData: function (filter) {
                return $.ajax({
                    type:"GET",
                    url:"assets/php/getbrands.php",
                    data:filter
                });
            },
        },

        fields:[
            {
                name:"id",
                type:"hidden",
                css:'hide'
            },
            {
                name:"name",
                type:"text",
                width:150,
                validate:"required"
            },
            {
                type: "control"
            }
        ]
    });
</script>
```

Comment: have you included all libraries properly? looks like `.jsGrid` is not known to the script.

Comment: yes im sure i included and added whole thing to the question to be clear

Comment: what's your jquery version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was

```
<script src="assets/vendors/js/vendor.bundle.base.js"></script>
```

These scripts' function names were overlapping with jsGrid function names so that was blocking browser/javascript to read functions properly i moved those script to where they were required so theres no problem for now thank you for all your help and effort..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your files are all correct, I would recommend wrapping your jquery function calls in `document.ready`. This way they are only ran once the DOM is ready to be edited via Javascript.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#brands_table").html("asd");
    $("#brands_table").jsGrid({
        width: "100%",
        height: "400px",

        filtering: true,
        inserting:true,
        editing:true,
        sorting:true,
        paging:true,
        autoload:true,
        pageSize:10,
        pageButtonCount:5,
        deleteConfirm:"Silmek istediğinize emin misiniz?",

        controller:{
            loadData: function (filter) {
                return $.ajax({
                    type:"GET",
                    url:"assets/php/getbrands.php",
                    data:filter
                });
            },
        },

        fields:[
            {
                name:"id",
                type:"hidden",
                css:'hide'
            },
            {
                name:"name",
                type:"text",
                width:150,
                validate:"required"
            },
            {
                type: "control"
            }
        ]
    });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I get the same error but on vendor.bundle.base.js (last imported script before my script) and if i remove this line it gives the same error at script below my script

Comment: So it sounds like you have the same problem everywhere then. It is being ran before jquery is being loaded. You might end up just needing to wrap the various jquery function calls in document.ready.

Comment: if it was being ran before jquery is being loaded "$("#brands_table").html("asd");" this line wouldnt work..